# How to simply update a Table in a PyQt GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to create the basic look of my GUI with Qt-Designer, and add the functions via coding afterwards. Maybe there is already the Problem, but let's go on further.

My GUI that i created via Qt desinger consists of a 4x4 Table and a button.
When the Button is pressed, i want to write something in the cells of the Table.

(Sure, this in particular would be possible without using Qt desinger. But for the future there iwant to creat some more difficult GUIs. And therefore the Qt designer does save quite some time for a newbie like me :) )

The GUI code is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(686, 539)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 258, 223))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(say_hello)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "A"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "B"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "C"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "D"))
        testitem=QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, testitem)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(say_hello(testitem))

def say_hello(testitem):
    print("Hello you!")
    testitem.setText("Hi")
```

the GUI gets called from another file like that:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
import GUI_PyQtn

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QWidget, GUI_PyQtn.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My thoughts on my approach were, creating the Cell object and pass it to the function "say_hello". If the function would be inside the Ui_Form Class, it acutally called it not even once.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you're asking. And, **in any case**, and as probably shown in the header you removed and ignored, you're **not** supposed to edit files generated by pyuic.

Answer (score 0):

### I believe you can get what you're looking for with the following tweaks.

- Declare testitem with self in class Ui_Form
- Declare say_hello in class Ui_Form
- Pass testitem in say_hello by lambda
- No use click.connect() in retranslateUi

that's it

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(686, 539)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 258, 223))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        # declare testitem with self ih here
        self.testitem=QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        # pass testitem in say_hello
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.say_hello(self.testitem))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "A"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "B"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "C"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "D"))
        #self.testitem=QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, self.testitem)
        #self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        #self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.say_hello(testitem))

    # say_hello in class
    def say_hello(self, testitem):
        testitem.setText('Hi')
```